# How can I display a thumbnail image to Table Cell in xCode?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

As a Xcode beginner, I want to display a thumbnail in the table cell in my app. For now, I have this code which parses JSON data and posts it in the title and subtitle of the cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"receta"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"koha"];

    return cell;
}
```

How can I show a thumbnail in the right of the cell?

Thanks.

Comment: Create a custom cell that you can use with your own layout. Search Custom UITableViewCells on google.

Comment: Popeye, would you mind helping me with this? I searched, but I don't find anything useful for me, since I know a little about Xcode, it's my third time to open it today.

Comment: I would recommend some tutorials than. Here is a good tutorial http://blog.spritebandits.com/2012/03/13/creating-custom-uitableviewcells-from-xibs-step-by-step-tutorial/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to make a custom cell, you can create a `UIImageView` with your desired image and set it as the cell's `accessoryView`, which will show it on the right edge of the cell.  You also need to ensure that the height of the cell is tall enough to fit the image's height.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 100;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"some-image-name"]];

    return cell;
}
```

You can return a constant (I chose `100`) if the image will always be a fixed size, or you can check the `UIImage`'s `size` and return something like `size.height + 10` for some extra padding.

Comment: I would tend to say that isn't what the `accessoryView` is for but it would do the job. +1 for out the box thinking.

Comment: It's one approach if Amar doesn't want to make a custom cell